# Angularjs directive that resizes only width of the canvas

Tags: angularjs

How can we write a directive that changes only the width of a canvas?

Comment: I will give height via style... Maybe resizeX directive can accept a value to set the height too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is going to be pretty simple. Below is a simple directive to resize an element's width.

```
var ag = angular.module('ag', []);

var resizeX = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      resizeX: '='
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('resizeX', function(value) {
        element.css('width', value + 'px');
      });
    }
  };
};
ag.directive('resizeX', resizeX);
```

Just link the resizeX directive scope to a model in the element.

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/AVSautaZqQYBB5vCZGob?p=preview

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: your directive name is resizeX   why do we write resize-x in the html?    I am trying to set the width to %100 and set a custom heigt without stretching canvas...

Comment: Quoting from Angularjs website- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Comment: Please post your html content to have a clear understanding of what you are doing

Comment: Ok I have accepted your answer as true, changed my question and post another question ( that is more meaningful) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943246/angularjs-and-paper-js-full-width-specific-height-canvas