# angularjs and paper.js full width specific height canvas

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a navigation on top of my web page via canvas using angularjs and paperjs.

My angularjs directive that inits paper.js

```
.directive('draw', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        onResize = function (event){

            console.log('aaa')
        }

        function initPaper() {
            paper.install(window);
            paper.setup('canvas'); 
            view.onResize = onResize;
        }
        initPaper();
    }
};
```

if i write my nav canvas html like that:

```
<canvas id="canvas" draw style='width:100% height:35px' ></canvas>
```

everything works fine but elements on the canvas stretches according to canvas size ( I do not want any stretching  and paperjs onresize event does not work.

if i write my nav canvas html like that:

```
<canvas id="canvas" draw resize style='height:35px'></canvas>
```

canvas width is not full...

What can I do to create a canvas that is full width, 35px tall and does not stretches element on it when resized. And listens resize events via paperjs...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution as this:

html ( paperjs reacts to window resizings )

```
<canvas id="canvas" draw resize ></canvas>
```

inside angularjs directive via onResize event we get the window width and set...

```
onResize = function (event){
            view.viewSize = [event.size.width, 35]
        }
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way. I wonder if there is a better way...